# Changing batch scripts based on input and getting things returned from a file

Tags: batch-file

2 Questions:

1) Changing scripts based on input

Basically, say I have a file, like `search.html` that changes based on what you type in.
Aside from doing

```
set/p string=What would you like to search for?
echo ^<!DOCTYPE html^> >>file.html
echo ^<html^> >>file.html
echo ^<title^>^</title> >>file.html
echo ^<script language="JavaScript""^> >>file.html
echo string = '%site%'
...
```

Is there another way to do this?

2) Getting things returned from a file?

I have no example for this. I was simply wondering if you could start a file, use wait, and once it has closed get what was in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo OFF &setlocal
(
echo ^<!DOCTYPE html^>
echo ^<html^>
echo ^<title^>^</title^>
echo ^<script language="JavaScript""^>
echo string = '%site%'
)>file.html
```

> 2) Getting things returned from a file

```
@echo OFF &setlocal
FOR /f "delims=" %%a  IN (file.html) DO (
    ECHO(%%a
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to replace text in a file with something else.  You can get input and then replace a `MARKER` (text like that) with the input text.  VBS, Powershell, SED, AWK, and batch can do it.

Your second question is a bit short on detail - but FINDSTR etc can read lines from a file.

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly have to try that!